# What is meant by "Est-ce que tes copains aussi font du français?"

Tags: vocabulaire

Is this question asking whether or not my friends "make" french? What is meant by this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

*Easy French Step-by-Step* (Rochester) gives some examples of this idiom.

> faire des langues modernes (to study modern languages)
>   faire de la littérature (to study literature)
>   faire de la médecine (to study medicine)

The idiom means "to study". Thus your sentence could be translated as:

> Est-ce que tes copains aussi font du français?
>   **Are your friends also studying French?**

Comment: Thanks! I guess I didn't realize it could mean multiple things.

Answer (score 1):

***Faire*** is often translated by **to do** instead of **to make**.

Literally, this sentence means:

- Are your pals also **doing** French? (i.e. **studying** French)

From the [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/faire):

> **Faire**
>   ...
>   **D.**− Exercer (une activité suivie de façon régulière), employer son temps à.
>   ...
>   **1.** Domaine scol. et universitaire. Faire des études*, faire l'école buissonnière*; faire un doctorat, une licence.
>   − En partic.
>   ♦ **Faire** + art. partitif + subst. Étudier, pratiquer (une matière, une discipline). Faire des maths